# Decide if this language is context free

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I got this question for homework:

> Decide if this language is context free or not:
>
> $\qquad \{x@1^m: x \in \left\{0,1\right\}^*, m \in \mathbb{N}, x_m = 1\}$.

Intuitively I think it's not context-free because a $PDA$ can't remember the places of all the $1$'s in $x$.

I tried using the pumping lemma but couldn't find the right example to show the language is not context-free.

I'd be grateful for any lead.

Comment: Are you sure that $x@1^m$ is supposed to be the language of strings of 0 and 1 such that the $m^{th}$ symbol is a one?  And $m$ is the same for the whole language? - - - How many places can a PDA remember? - - - is this an exercise for a course on CF languages and PDA?

Comment: @babou I'm sure that is the language (of course there is a '@' sign in between. m is not the same for the whole language. for example, if x=0110101, the PDA will accept words in-which m is 2,3,5 or 7. m=1,4 and 6 will not be accepted in the PDA.

Comment: Hint: think nondeterministic. machine may guess and check.

Comment: @HendrikJan thanks, I'll try to think that way.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Following up on Hendrik Jan's hint, here is another way to view this language:
$$
\{ x1y@1z : x,y \in \{0,1\}^*, z \in \{1\}^*, |x| = |z| \}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

I think the context free grammar with these productions and starting symbol `S` produces your language (assuming words start at index 0):

**S -> 0S1 

S -> 1S1 

S -> 1X 

X -> 0X 

X -> 1X 

X -> @**

Explanation: You can produce any words from `{0,1}*` with index < `m`and add a `1`to the right part of the word. When you reach index `m`, you switch to `X` and continue the word from `{0,1}*`. You can end the word by producing an `@`.

Comment: This grammar derives $10$@, which isn't in the language: $S\Rightarrow 1X\rightarrow 10X\Rightarrow 10$@.

Comment: @Rick, it's just mis-indexing, if you call the first letter $x_0$ instead of $x_1$ then it works correctly. So this is a strong evidence that the question is CF (proven with a slight change to the above grammar).

Comment: Ran is right. As I said: "assumging words start at index 0". If words start at index 1, remove the Production S -> 1X and insert a new production S -> 1X1.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L = \{x@1m:x\in\{0,1\}^∗,m\in N,x_m=1\}$.

A language $L$ is context-free when a context-free grammar $G = \langle\Sigma, N, S, R\rangle$ such that $L(G) = L$ (the language of $G$ is the same as $L$).

\begin{align}
G = \langle\{0, 1\}, \{S, X\}, S, \{&\\
&\qquad X \rightarrow 0X,\\
&\qquad X \rightarrow 1X,\\ 
&\qquad X \rightarrow \epsilon,\\
&\qquad S \rightarrow 0S1,\\
&\qquad S \rightarrow 1S1,\\ 
&\qquad S \rightarrow 1X@1 \\
&\}\rangle
\end{align}

Comment: I find it hard to spot the difference from [Dezi's '14 answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/35151).